# javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory - how to add a TrustStore

Tags: android, httpsurlconnection

I am using a custom SSLSocketFactory class that removes SSLv3 from enabled protocols. I am not able to figure out how to attach a Truststore to the socket factory that is set to the HttpsURLConnection. All the examples that I have seen so far use org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.

If you could guide me on either 1) How to remove SSLv2 and SSLv3 from the protocols using apache SSLSocketFactory or 2) How to add a Truststore to javax SSLSocketFactory, I would appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to 2) - I created a SSLContext, set the TrustStore and assigned its SSLSocketFactory to the CustomSSLSocketFactory where the SSLv3 was removed.